# Bootstrap responsive Youtube embed not permitting cross origin framing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

After attempting to embed a video the site will not display it.

With the following simple HTML code:

```
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">  
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n01ogXL-q9I"></iframe>
    </div>
```

I am presented with the console error:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n01ogXL-q9I does not permit
>   cross-origin framing.

Is there a simple secure fix? I believe this relates back to security in some for to prevent clickjacking attacks? I would prefer it if Youtube embeds were visible to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Simple reason the video not being displayed is that the video needs to be embedded before using it in any other website.

Your code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">  
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n01ogXL-q9I"></iframe>
```

You need to always replace `/watch?v=` with `/embed/` after `www.youtube.com` as shown below:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/n01ogXL-q9I"></iframe>
</div>
```